# How to find docker.socket file after change of docker root folder ?

Tags: docker

Docker service is correctly setting up.

Before long, I change the root directory of Docker from /var/lib/docker to /opt/docker.

I can't find the docker.socket file, in order to share it with another container (Docker In Docker, DIND).

Docker info does not display any information about the location of the socker ?, How can I find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify your OS.
For example, on Ubuntu 14.04 it's `/var/run/docker.sock`

I believe that Docker socket file is not expected to appear at `/var/lib/docker` on any default setup

Also, if you are on CentOS of Fedora, take a look on http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/

Comment: Docker is installed on top of CentOS7

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info by running:

```
docker context inspect | jq -r .[0].Endpoints.docker.Host | sed "s^unix://^^"
```

This add the extra advantage that if you run on docker rootless, you can get the socket location dynamically in a bash script.